# <native.h> missing, any idea where that should be?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I've been tasked to recompile an old (2005) DLL from 32bits to 64bits.

The projects first told me that `<jni.h>` could not be found, upon searching, I found that I needed to add an include directory. Now it tells me it can't find `<native.h>`, but this generic term doesn't return good result on search...

I'm trying to figure out what it contains to fullfill my needs. Any idea?

Oh yeah, I also had a old include directory : `g:\MSSDKJava4.0\include`. Of course, I don't have that on my computer and upon searching and [this SDK seems to be depreciated](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/Interoperability/Java/Default.aspx).

Comment: Do you need the file at all? What errors do you get if you remove the inclusing of the file?

Comment: crash at (oh I love that comment!) : `return RNIVER;    /* RNIVER is defined in Native.h */ ` (RNIVER being a DWORD being an unsigned long).

Comment: Yes, that looks very much like RNI and more than a recompile as Michael pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Your DLL is not using JNI, but Microsoft's proprietary native interface called [RNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface#Microsoft.27s_RNI) distributed with its Visual J++ product. I suspect that you're pretty much completely out of luck here, as even if you could find a copy of Visual J++, it would not support 64bit.

Basically your situation is exactly what people had in mind when they attacked Microsoft for trying to "embrace and extend" Java with proprietary add-ons.

Looks like you're in for a port / complete rewrite.

Comment: How could it be j++? It really look like c++. (.cpp files, syntax...), although, I never saw J++...

Comment: @Kraz: J++ was basically Microsoft's attempt to create a proprietary Java dialect under their control, AKA "embrace and extend". RNI was the proprietary equivalent of standard Java JNI, i.e. the interface between J++ and native C/C++ code.